# Want to Show Which Test Validation Step Failed Azure DevOps Test Report

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In the Azure DevOps Test Report for a certain test plan, I see the different test cases. If a particular test case fails, I would like to see at which validation step it failed in the report. Is there any way to add a column or feature that displays this information?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzOZK.jpg For example, this picture, the test case failed, but I would like to see the report include which validation step failed (step 1 or step 1.1). Right now when downloading the test report there is no feature that includes this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to add a column or feature that displays this
> information?

I'm afraid this is currently impossible to achieve, azure devops does not support adding test step related information in the test report.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.